# Python Logging "KeyError" when loading fileConfig

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to write out to a log in python; I would like to be able to load the configuration from a file, but I am getting an error after calling:

> > > logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/logging/config.py", line 157, in fileConfig
> > >           log.addHandler(handlers[hand])
> > >       KeyError: 'simpleHandler'

My config is:

```
  [loggers]
  keys=root

  [handlers]
  keys=simpleHandler

  [formatters]
  keys=simpleFormatter

  [logger_root]
  level=DEBUG
  handlers=simpleHandler

  [handler_simpleHandler]
  formatter=simpleFormatter
  class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
  filename=/tmp/test.log
  maxBytes=31457280
  level=DEBUG

  [formatter_simpleFormatter]
  format=%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s
  datefmt=%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S
```

please help me determine what the error is, thanks.

Comment: You are using Python Version 2.4? That's very old! Why do you use this old version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your filehandler:

```
    [handler_simpleHandler]
    formatter=simpleFormatter
    class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
    maxBytes=31457280
    level=DEBUG
    args=('/tmp/test.log',)
```

Comment: This worked! From another post on here I also derived this:

`args=('/tmp/test.log','a','maxBytes=31457280', 'backupCount=15')`

Answer (score 0):

No doubt the key `'simpleHandler'` is missing from whatever structure it is supposed to be found in.

I suggest placing your `handler_foo` sections before your `handlers` section - see if that helps. If that doesn't help,  find some other way to give your hoped-for handler a name.